# android not working with xml urls

Tags: android, xml, json

I'm testing to get my xml values using this code

```
   static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
static final String KEY_DESC = "description";

XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

// looping through all item nodes <item>     
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    String name = parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME); // name child value
    String cost = parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST); // cost child value
    String description = parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC); // description child value
}
```

the child elements of the xml was the same, the only difference is that I'm getting the xml on asp.net *10.0.2.2:57843/menus/json/getall* with structure xml of this

```
 **<ArrayOfitem>**
       <item>
           <cost>445</cost>
           <description>sarap</description>
           <id>1</id>
           <name>pizza</name>
       </item>
```

**compared to**
http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml

```
**<menu>**
       <item>
          <id>1</id>
          <name>Margherita</name>
          <cost>155</cost>
          <description>Single cheese topping</description>
        </item>
```

and I'm having a logcat error of

```
07-08 04:10:10.329: E/Error:(1968): Unexpected token (position:TEXT {"ExceptionType"...@1:922 in java.io.StringReader@b5182a40) 
07-08 04:10:10.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1968): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 04:10:10.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1968): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.xmlparsing/com.androidhive.xmlparsing.AndroidXMLParsingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 04:10:10.329: E/AndroidRuntime(1968):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)


ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.xmlparsing/com.androidhive.xmlparsing.AndroidXMLPa‌​rsingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.androidhive.xmlparsing.AndroidXMLParsingActivity.onCreate(AndroidXMLParsingA‌​ctivity.java:43

line 43 NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM); and we got the same parent node of <item>
```

may someone have the time to explain or correct me with the problem?,,
thanks.

Comment: post the full stacktrace and the relevant code

Comment: I'm testing this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/ what I only change is the url with my own web service. The problem is that I can't fetch my xml using the code. I had similar xml nodes with a difference only of the parent node here in him http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml he had this <menu> and I got an <ArrayOfitem> with ascending child nodes of <cost><description><id> and <name> here is the full stack trace 
`

Comment: `error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
Unexpected token (position:TEXT {"ExceptionType"...@1:922 in java.io.StringReader@b5182318) 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.xmlparsing/com.androidhive.xmlparsing.AndroidXMLParsingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.androidhive.xmlparsing.AndroidXMLParsingActivity.onCreate(AndroidXMLParsingActivity.java:43`

Comment: what's on line 43 AndroidXMLParsingA‌​ctivity?

Comment: NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

and we got the same parent node of <item>